# MySQL IN values from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query like

```
select prod_name 
from ct_products 
where id in ( (select prod_id 
               from ct_recommend 
               where cat_id=12) ) and status > 0
```

However, because the subquery return a string that looks like 1,2,3 instead of rows of result, the query doesn't work the way it should. Is there any way to format the subquery result so that it works in the IN clause?

Thank you!

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us, because this does work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0f10/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give this a try,

```
select prod_name 
from ct_products 
where FIND_IN_SET(ID,(select prod_id from ct_recommend where cat_id=12)) <> 0 
      and status > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT prod_name 
FROM ct_products cp 
WHERE STATUS > 0 AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ct_recommend cr WHERE cp.id = cr.prod_id AND cat_id=12);
```